# Result to Map in Scala Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I am trying to get a map of name -> id from the resultset.

```
val isp = SQL("select id, name from internet_service_providers").map { x => x[String]("name") -> x[String]("id") }
```

I am unable to understand why I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$$anonfun$3.apply(SqlStatementParser.scala:43)
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$$anonfun$3.apply(SqlStatementParser.scala:43)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers$class.parse(RegexParsers.scala:148)
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$.parse(SqlStatementParser.scala:11)
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SqlStatementParser.scala:26)
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SqlStatementParser.scala:26)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at anorm.SqlStatementParser$.parse(SqlStatementParser.scala:26)
at anorm.package$.SQL(package.scala:40)
at com.gumgum.nativead.NativeInventoryApp$.main(NativeInventoryApp.scala:49)
at com.gumgum.nativead.NativeInventoryApp.main(NativeInventoryApp.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I am guessing that my way of creating the map in code above might be completely wrong or there is a scala version mismatch in the libs used.
I am using scala 2.11.5 and anrom 2.4.0-M3 built with scala 2.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;` is not from Anorm but from `Predef`: the `->` operator is not found to build tupple, which is quite weird. I would suggest to check your scala version and dependencies, to be sure there is not several scala lib pulled.

Then if you want to  turn a `Row` as a tuple, `SqlParser.flatten` can be used.

Finally as the result will be a list of tuple, `.toMap` can be used.

```
import anorm.SqlParser.{ flatten, str }
SQL("...").as((str("name") ~ str("id")).map(flatten).*).toMap
```

Comment: all dependencies have 2.11 but i see gradle download 2.11.5 and 2.11.6 version of scala can minor versions be an issue ?

Comment: It depends on your dev env. Really don't think that related specifically to Anorm.

Comment: I was running a spark app and it was running in scala 2.10 which where as Anorm libs were built with 2.11 hence this issue